# Code to execute a file on c:\

Tags: java, executable

Ok, so heres what I need to learn. I have 2 java programs that I would like to start up by only using 1. (The programs executes both programs on startup and then exits after it has done its job).

Comment: *"Ok, so heres what I need to learn"*  This isn't school.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: did you even try to google it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`java.lang.Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html), in particular the various `exec()` methods.